# Jasper Report Cross Tabs and Column Name ordering

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

Is there a way that I can order the columns in a cross tab based on an list of Strings?

The items in the data do not contain any columns other than the columns listed in the String list. [ArrayList].

This array list is passed into the report as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had to append the order number to the title of the cross tab. [The data was not coming in exactly how the cross tab wanted to display it, so I couldn't claim the data was presorted]

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me. I append the order number field in the select query and then removed the number for esthetic purpose with an expression like this `RIGHT($V{name},LEN($V{name}) - 1)`